# Regarding the use of API's

Tags: api

My app is a Personal Assistant who's main job is to redirect the user to something that complies with his/her wishes. I realize, for example that AllRecipies.com has no API. My question is that can I, say open the browser app with the url as

> http://allrecipes.com/search/results/?wt=`QUERY`>&sort=re.

Is this considered as using their API? Not just AllRecipies, but numerous other such services. If I am using this method, then do I have to request API key, etc? I am not retrieving anything. I am simply redirecting the user to their page with the query pre-written. Does this require all the licensing fees, API Key, etc?

Do I have to agree to this fees(If they ask), Request API Key, etc?

Comment: You say "for example that AllRecipies.com has no API". Do they have an API? if they dont then you will not be able to make network calls to get or post data through out their database. If they have an API then most likely you have to register for an app or get an API Key , read their documentation on how to do network calls and then your good to go

Comment: "If I am using this method, then do I have to request API key" Depends upon the requirements of the specific API. Some APIs don't require API keys; some do for specific calls; some do for all calls.

Comment: As i have mentioned I don't want the data. I just want to redirect the user to the webpage and the url - 

http://allrecipes.com/search/results/?wt=QUERY>&sort=re.                                    Where QUERY is a varying parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the particular URL in question, it is simply an HTML web server URL, rather than a web API, as such. You can still get data out of it, but you'd have to parse the HTML yourself to extract what you want from the HTML response.

They may have an API that you can use to access data more directly as JSON, XML, etc, but you'll have to look into that yourself. And you will possibly require an API key to access it. But perhaps not, if it's publicly available and they don't care how many calls they get to it by anonymous users.

You may find this resource useful. It contains a lot of open APIs and code snippets to access them: http://www.programmableweb.com/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I do not want to parse any object out of it. Just direct the user to the webpage. But I have a varying parameter. So will that be a problem?

Comment: Also this site in particular has no API. And as far as I know, it had one. But later on retired it

Comment: In that case, you're fine to simply enter the search query parameter into the URL and simply direct your users to that page. That works. It's just a simple GET request to the web page in question. No API key or fees required for that.

Comment: I have this doubt. Because when I contacted wolfram alpha's help desk and asked this same question. They said it is a use of API's and I would have to pay. Same conditions. No offence, but are you sure I don't need to?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. It's a publicly available URL. Which you can access via your browser and make exactly the same requests upon it. If you were hammering the web server with requests, then that would get you into trouble for a different reason, but you're perfectly allowed to make simple web requests to a page using a GET with a variable in the URL. Like so... http://allrecipes.com/search/results/?wt=rice&sort=re

Comment: Just one last thing. Sorry for the disturbance, does this hold true with eventful.com as well. It has its own api's. So is this method against that?

Comment: You can check that in their documentation here https://api.eventful.com/                 Sorry for being a total newbie on this subject

Comment: That one requires you apply for an API key. It states that on the page you supplied. Whether it is free or not, I don't know.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mano. Thanks so much again!

Answer (score 0):

If you are simply trying to hit a URL or directing a user to this particular URL which you already know and is static meaning you always hit the same url without change in parameters, then this is not considered an API call and will not be requiring any API key. 
However, if they have some APIs exposed, you will need to go through their documentation and using this API most likely requires the use of an API key(alhough this might not be true always). Usually, most platforms have a bunch of APIs available for different scenarios and these are called based on user specific parameters and requirements.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I do not want to parse any object out of it. Just direct the user to the webpage. But I have a varying parameter. So will that be a problem?

Comment: In case you are not parsing the result object and simply directing to a page, this is not an API call. You can simply go ahead and use it and you do not need to request an API key. Also to give you a tip, in most of API calls, the api key is itself a parameter in the request.

Comment: Thank you. And yes im not parsing the result. And also I have this doubt. Because when I contacted wolfram alpha's help desk and asked this same question. They said it is a use of API's and I would have to pay. Same conditions. No offence, but are you sure I don't need to?

Comment: Yes, the url you have mentioned is a simple Web url and it is only generating simple HTML pages by making GET service calls. So you do not  have to pay anything or ask for an API key.. This is same as .. can i access amazon.com with 'ipad' as its parametes ;) yes obv you can and it wont be an API call

Comment: Just one last thing. Sorry for the disturbance, does this hold true with eventful.com as well. It has its own api's. So is this method against that?You can check that in their documentation here api.eventful.com Sorry for being a total newbie on this subject

Comment: Sorry Learner, even though the answer was correct I couldn't mark 2 answers are correct. So I had to base it on the timing. Thanks so much for your help. I still up voted (Someone down voted already so my up vote kind off made -1 to 0. Sorry. ButThanks so much for your help.